# How do you break a Loop with a key press without using a module that is not built in to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a program that counts to a number that the user inputs.

I'm trying to let the user press a key at anytime to pause the counting and bring up a menu of options, but I can not figure out how to achieve such a task without relying on a module that is not built in to python 3.

Any Help would be much Appreciated.

Here's a Sample Code:

```js
number = int(input("Enter a Number you want to Count To: "))


        if type(number) == int:

            print("""
To Pause the Counting Process at Anytime Press Any Key...
""")

            input("Press Enter to Continue...")

            print("Counting In: 3")
            time.sleep(1)

            print("Counting In: 2")
            time.sleep(1)

            print("Counting In: 1")
            time.sleep(1)
            
            for n in range(0, number):
                print(n + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` to check for data on stdin.

```
import time
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    import msvcrt
    def checkKey():
        return msvcrt.kbhit()

else:
    from select import select
    def checkKey():
        rlist, _, _ = select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0.0)
        if rlist:
            sys.stdin.readline().strip()
            return True
        return False


print("Press ENTER key to exit")
for n in range(0, 20):
    print(n)
    time.sleep(1)
    if checkKey():
        break
```

Comment: I just tried out your solution and I received this error: OSError: [WinError 10093] Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed.